# how can I use windows azure storage with transloadit?

Tags: azure-storage, transloadit

I have read the documentation of transloadit and it buckles up nicely with amazon s3, i am using windows azure storage and my videos are already there how can i make transloadit to pull those videos from my azure storage account for encoding?

Comment: Without having used Azure, would it be possible to enable ftp/sftp on it somehow? Transloadit support that..?

Comment: What i can do provide an absolute url to the video to transloadit and then when video is converted i need a url to download the video

Comment: Ah that is supported indeed. Transloadit keeps temporary results around for 24 hours. The links to those are inside the assembly status, and could be downloaded upon assembly completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Transloadit does not provide a store robot for windows azure storage, so i figured it out transloadit saves the encoded files for few hours so what i do when assembly has been completed i fetch the files manually from transloadit storage to my windows azure storage account

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform that currently Transloadit support [Importing](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/file-importing/azure-import/) and [Exporting](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/file-exporting/azure-store/) for Azure.